# Select a valid choice. '"xxx" is not one of the available choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, python-3.x

I know many people have been asking this question "***Select a valid choice. 'xxx' is not one of the available choices.***" but I  just think my scenario is somewhat different.

Well, what I was trying to do is; I have an input choice field that allow someone to choose between two choices (Let's say choices are A and B). Hence if someone decides to choose choice A; some of available input fields will disappear while holding default values that i have assigned to them (this is to allow form submission. I can't make them required=False since if you choose   choice B, this input fields will appear and if required=False they may be submitted without values.Something that I don't want):

***forms.py***
cars = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = cars.objects.all(),widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control seleckpicker','required':'True'}),empty_label="Choose car") . Hence if it return empty list if nothing in table. So what I was trying to do is append value.

under html page
    $('select[name=fuel] option:eq(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#id_cars').append($('', {
            value: 'AA',
            text: 'AA',
          }));
    $('id_total_fruits').val(0);

So what I was trying to do is append value to id_cars incase the dropdown is empty field
This is why I decided to append value to be able to submit my though; even though doing this makes me getting this error:

"***Select a valid choice. 'xxx' is not one of the available choices.***"

I hope I make myself clear. Anyone with solution please...????

Comment: You need to show some Django code.

Comment: This is what I have in my forms.py car = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = cars.objects.all(),widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control seleckpicker','required':'True'}),empty_label="Choose car") . Hence if it return empty list if nothing in  table. So what I was trying to do is append value ($('#id_cars').append($('<option>', {
        value: 'AA',
        text: 'AA',
      }));) so as to hold value when submitting to views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question a bit here, so if im way off base let me know and i'll delete my answer haha.

why not do an if or switch block statement switched based on the selections to set the required attribute

ie.

```
`$('#selector').on('change', function() {
       if ($(this).val() == "A"))  {
             $('#inputA').prop('required', true);
             $('#inputB').removeAttr('required');
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "B"))  {
             $('#inputB').prop('required', true);
             $('#inputA').removeAttr('required');
        }
  });
```

Thats what i have used on some of my pages in this scenario.